# Clear HTML form that has its reset Value

Tags: php, html, forms

Ive a form that have certain input text. all of them has their own reset value.. 
for example ...

```
<input type="text" 
       name="<?php echo $row['FieldName'];?>"
       id="<?php echo $row['FieldName'];?>" 
       class="required" 
       style="font:12px Verdana ; width:250px;" 
       value="<?php echo $row2[$nameROW]?>" />
<?php }
```

thus when i use normal RESET function..it will not clear up my form. because of its reset value has been set already...

so how can i totally CLEAR not RESET the form??

Comment: Unclear question is unclear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid fields being reset to their initial values, you'll need to actually cycle through all of the input fields, textfields, and select elements, individually setting their values to an empty string, checked properties to false, etc.

You can see an example of what this might look like online at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-clear-form/, or what a jQuery solution (which is a bit more concise) would look like at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-clear-form/.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy to use (pure js) function that you can use to reset any form by id or name:

```
// License: WTFPL
function clearForm(id)
{
    // find form by its id or name
    var form = document.getElementById(id) || document[id] || id;

    // cycle through elements
    for (var i = 0, item; item = form.elements[i]; ++i) {
        switch (item.type) {
            case 'select-one':
                item.selectedIndex = 0;
                break;

            case 'select-multiple':
                for (var j = 0, option; option = item.options[j]; ++j) {
                    option.selected = false;
                }
                break;

            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                item.checked = false;
                break;

            default:
                item.value = '';
        }
    }​​​​​​
}
```

To call it:

```
clearForm('id or name of your form');
```

Comment: i ve tried this one .. but i dont know why its not working ..later i tried with  @Jonathan Sampson example. it works

Comment: @jannatulalia How did you call it? I didn't see your complete form, so I can't give you a concrete answer that applies exactly to your needs.

Comment: i call it using input button.
<input onclick="clearForm(upDate)" type="button" value="Clear All" />

Comment: @jannatulalia hmm, if you have a `<form name="foo" .. />` you call this function as `clearForm('foo')`

Comment: <input onclick="clearForm('upDate')" type="button" value="Clear All" /> 
like this?

Comment: @jannatulalia yeah, that should work. i've slightly updated the code to also support `clearForm(this.form)`

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan is correct but it is incomplete. Here is the full solution:

```
for ( i = 0; i < document.myForm.elements.length; i++ )
  document.myForm.elements[i].fieldName.value = "";
```

Please let us know if you need further help. This iterates through every item in the form and then blanks them. Let us know if you need more help.

Comment: ive tried @Jonathan Sampson one. it works. thanks for responding ;)

Answer (score 0):

use the following jQuery to set specified field to blank:

```
$("#btn_reset").click(function(){
     $("input:text[id=xxx]").val("");
});
```

Use the following jQuery to set all fields values to blank:

```
$("#btn_reset").click(function(){
    $(":input").val("");
});
```

In the above examples, #btn_reset is the ID of the Reset button. You will also need to place the above script inside your script tag inside the normal $(document).ready() function's handler of your page. of course, the above will require you to include the jQuery library first in the top of the page. If you have any questions please let me know.

Here is the complete HTML file that works:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE></TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn_reset").click(function() {
                $("input:text[id=xxx]").val("");
            });
        });
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="xxx" id="xxx" value="default"  />
            <input type="button" value="Reset" id="btn_reset" />
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please note you need change the button type from reset to button as otherwise after jQuery sets the value then the reset button behavior will again set the value to the default value which we dont want.

Comment: ive tried, and put it in $(document).ready() function's handler and include jQuery header but i dont know what's wrong with my code.. its not working ..later i try with Jonathan Sampson sample..and it works.

Comment: I edited my answer and provided a complete HTML with jQuery code and form that works in my computer! HTH

Comment: i got this. can 2 function be in it? 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_reset").click(function() {
                $("input:text[id=xxx]").val("");
            });
 $("#itemReg").validate();
 
 });

Comment: sure, they are normal functions and can be as many lines of text as is needed!

Comment: And if you find my answer useful, please mark it accordingly! Cheers!